# How to fetch input field value using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to fetch input feild value using XSLT below is the Example:

Example : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_if

and replace xslt code with the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="testTextBox" value="testValue"/>
    value here -->> <xsl:value-of select=".//x:TextBox[@Name = 'testTextBox']" />
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:if test="price>10">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
   </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then below you will see the input field - So my requirement are like this way:

- What ever text user write in input field i want to show that value using XLT in front of that input field .

Thanks
Sushil

Comment: good try for a beginner though, so +1

Comment: Please, include the source XML document (don't just redirect), and also specify the exact wanted result from the transformation. w3schools are not a good XSLT learning site -- see why here: http:www.w3fools.com

Comment: Dimitre is right! @Sushil, I have made small edition to the code, which will copy text from textbox to span area.. but I'm afraid it doesn't work in W3Schools try it window..

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with XSLT. It is DOM you are looking for, probably you should go for browser script like Javascript!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function copytext()
            {
            document.getElementById("copytext").innerHTML=document.getElementById("inputText").value;
            }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="copytext()">
          <input id="inputText" type="text" name="testTextBox" value="testValue" onkeydown="copytext()"/>
          value here -->> <span id="copytext"/>
          <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
          <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Artist</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
              <xsl:if test="price>10">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Meanwhile I will try something using javascript on my end and let you know.

Comment: @SushilRaghav, this doesn't work on w3schools.. they have disabled the scripting!

Comment: so go to this link: http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php.. paste your input XML and XSLT, 2)copy the output to a new text file, save it as (somefilename) *.html or *.htm, 3)open it in a browser, (ie, firefox, opera, or chrome etc)